# How to efficiently work with a dictionary of thousands of DataFrames in string format?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary with about 10,000 keys, where each key, holds a string like this:

```
my_string = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100,size=(3000, 11))).to_string()
```

Each string, if converted to `DataFrame` is of size between 1000 and 5000 in rows, but always 11 columns.

In the end, I would need each string in either a `np.array` or in a `pd.DataFrame` in order to work with it.

**My question is**: What is quick format to deliver the full information?
Is it best to keep it as a dictionary of thousands of strings or is it better to make some kind of a `np.array` or `xarray` which is holding a 3d object?

The problem with the latter is that the row size is different, so I need to probably fill with `nan` values to make them the same length or something else.

What is the best practice in such cases? I am trying to avoid loops, as it will be super time consuming.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're solving? You create large data frames, convert them to strings and use them as dictionary keys, then convert back (interesting, what values look like). This task looks weird to me.

Comment: I don't create the dataframes, I read the like that (they are stored in string format... who knows why).
So basically when I read the data, it is one giant dictionary, with thousands of keys, where each key is one giant string and the string is a dataframe in the format which I describe above.
Does this help?

Comment: wait - your  dictionary is a string of a dataframes?

Comment: No, this doesn't help much. I would dig into data and search for more optimal solution to read them. However, it depends on a goal. I still have no idea what problem you're solving. If you need to read the data only once, probably, simple loop will be ok. If you have a "data stream", then you should optimize reading function.

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are CSV, with fixed numbers of columns (you say you always have 11 columns and 3000-5000 rows), then you can dump them altogether to a file and read data frame from that file.
This is quite fast.

If it is not CSV, then anyway, you can cut  header and footer, and concatenate them to a file.

Next variant: wrap that dictionary into a subclass of `StringIO` or file-like object that would return string keys in `read` method and pass the object to `pandas.read_csv`